# Simplifying a complex regex

Tags: regular-expression

I am programmatically generating a very lengthy regex expression in a lua script I'm developing. It works, but at 960 characters, I can't help thinking it can be simplified a bit. However, I can't think of a way to do that without breaking it. In a nutshell, it looks for a string of 1 or more space-separated predefined keywords. A much-shortened version of the regex looks like this. You can see the major portion of it, the keyword list, is repeated.

```
\(big\|hairy\|regex\)\( \+\(big\|hairy\|regex\)\)*
```

To remove the duplication, I could use this one. The problem here is that the string starts with a space; whereas, I need it to start with any of the keywords.

```
\( \+\(big\|hairy\|regex\)\)\+
```

Of course the next regex doesn't work because `\1` refers to the text that was matched and not the regex that found it.

```
\(big\|hairy\|regex\)\( \+\1\)*
```

Can the regex be written so that the keyword list appears only once, but still matches correctly?

Comment: Does size really matter if you are generating it programmatically? No one will read it so why bother? Performance?

Comment: Actually, I **was** having performance issues at one point. I solved that by adding `\%#=1` to the beginning to use the old regex engine. I'll revisit that when I try Vivian's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
 *\zs\( *\<\(big\|hairy\|regex\)\>\)\+
```

That I would rewrite:

```
\v *\zs( *<(big|hairy|regex)>)+
```

The first  `*` eat the leading spaces if any.

They will not be part of the matching string because of the `\zs` that define the start of the matching.

The repetition don't force a set of   between the keywords but because of the `<` and `>` you are forced to have at least a non `word` but because only   are authorized in the regex you should have the desired result.

Comment: This is perfect. I even was able to remove the regex engine selection: `\%#=1`, mentioned in the comment above. Nice suggestion to use the `\v` flag too. It's much more readable now. Thanks, Vivian.

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for the feedback :-)